# cannot import tensorflow (installed with anaconda) in Visual Studio IDE

Tags: visual-studio, tensorflow, anaconda

Follow [these steps](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows), I successfully installed Tensorflow 1.0.0 of GPU version on my win10 laptop, using anaconda virtual environment (I know little about this, just follow the tips)

I run the HelloWorld code in interactive mode like this:

```
activate tensorflow
python
import tensorflow as tf
# ...
```

However, I cannot run it when I write in anaconda's editor or Visual Studio 2015 (community edition). It says

> no module named tensorflow

My config in VS is:
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBFrt.png)

So, can anyone give some tips on how to code tensorflow program happily in VS? Thx!

Comment: Does Visual Studio IDE has the conda package installation directories on its python path?

Comment: @scai Did you mean the last configuration item in my picture? Perhaps it is the reason, so can you explain more specifically to me? Is "PYTHON_PATH" here equal to my system environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create an environment in Anaconda using the following command.

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow
```

Navigate to Anaconda -> Environments -> you will see `tf` environment. Select that, then launch VS code.

If you need other packages installed into the same environment you can use the following command. (Eg: to install pytest)

```
conda install -n tf pytest
```